# Prove that if $x,y \in S$, then $x+y \in S$ using partial order relation properties

Tags: solution-verification, relations

Let $S  \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and for any $x,y  \in \mathbb{N}, x\rho y$ if and only if there exist $z \in S$ such that $x+z=y$. Show that if $\rho$ is a partial order relation then

(a) $0 \in S$

(b) If $x,y \in S$ then $x+y \in S$

Since $\rho$ is reflexive, $x\rho x$ so that $x+0=x$ then 0 $\in S$

The second question I can't prove it right. [image: image of the question]

Comment: The image reads like it's from a quiz or test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can view the relation in the following way: $x\rho y\iff y-x\in S$. Suppose that $x,y\in S$. Then
\begin{equation*}
0\rho y ~(\text{as } y\in S), \text{ and also } y\rho(x+y) ~ (\text{as } x\in S).\end{equation*}
By transitivity one obtains $0\rho (x+y)$, i.e., $x+y\in S$.

Comment: Wow! You've made it looks so easy, thanks a lot. can you recommend any book or website to enhance myself in solving these types of proofs

Comment: I think there is a minor typo. Did you mean xpy ⟺ (y-x)∈S?, regardless, elegent answer! So one only needs a transitive relation, rather than  a partial order.